# Extracting configmaps from services in kubernetes cluster using a spring microservice

Tags: java, spring, kubernetes, configmap

We are trying to get live configuration data from our kubernetes cluster. Therefore we would like to read the configmaps from each of our services.

Is there a way to exctract this data with a spring microservice which runs alongside the rest of the services?

Or are there other (better?) ways / tools to get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Kubernetes APIs you can get the configmaps you need. I am not familiar with the Java client, but here it is:

https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java

You can retrieve a list of configmaps and their contents using these APIs. Your application will need a cluster role and a cluster role binding to allow it reading from configmap resources if you're using RBAC.

Answer (score 0):

To extract information you can just query the Kubernetes API, likely in your case using the [Java Kubernetes client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java). Likely the biggest issue you will face will be ensuring you have read access for the namespace(s) that the ConfigMaps are in.

The bigger question about a 'better way' is trying to understand *why* you want to read all of the ConfigMaps for your applications. The goal you are trying to accomplish will guide the solution.